# Как получить значение из input, до первой запятой?

Tags: javascript

как по нажатию кнопки переменной присвоить значение input(всё, что было введено до первой запятой)

Answer (score 2):

```
let variable = "";
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    variable = input.value.split(",")[0];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
text = document.querySelector('#data').value;

pos = text.indexOf(',');
pos = pos == -1 ? text.length : pos

part = text.substring(0, pos);

console.log(part);
```

```html
<input type = 'text' value = '1234,5678,90' id = 'data'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю text.value.split(",")[0] подойдет.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("but");
let text = document.getElementById("text");

button.addEventListener("click", ()=>console.log(text.value.split(",")[0]))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">

<input type="button" id="but" value="Click">
```